# remove every nth word from file

Tags: python

The function should return the rest of the words from the file, just not the nth words.
I've got the opening, reading and closing the text file down, but I've been struggling to figure out the rest. I tried using append but quickly realized that's not the way to go about it.

My failed coding so far:

```
def message(fname, n):

    infile = open(fname,'r')
    mess = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    mess.append('')
    return mess
```

So it should return the rest of the words from the file, just not the nth words.

Comment: What index are you referring to?

Comment: Maybe I might be wording it wrong, but the function should remove every nth word from a text file and return the rest of the words remaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could read the entire file into a list and use the del statement to remove every n-th item.

```
def remove_every_nth_word_from_file(filename, n):
    with open(filename) as f:
        words = f.read().split()
        del words[n - 1::n]
    return words
```

f.read() function reads the entire file as a string; split() function splits this string by whitespace; words[n - 1::n] is a list slice that says, starting at (n - 1)-th position, include every n-th item; del statement removes this slice from the list.

Comment: Could you explain what [n - 1::n] is saying? I'm still new to python.

Comment: This is slicing syntax explained [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html).  [n-1::n] says, starting at (n - 1)-th position in the list, include every n-th item.

Comment: Okay thank you! Based off your coding I wrote mine and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

To remove every n<sup>th</sup> word, the pseudocode is to read every word and write them all out except the ones where `wordnumber modulo n` is equal to 0.

In other words:

```
nth = 7
wordnumber = 0
while not end-of-file:
    read word
    wordnumber = wordnumber + 1
    if wordnumber % nth is not 0:
        write word
```

That's it really. But don't make the mistake of thinking that's Python. My pseudo-code looks remarkably like Python since that language is ideal for the use, but you can't just plug it into a Python interpreter and expect it to work as is.

Of course, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it into Python, or any other normal language for that matter (normal in the sense of languages with `while` and `if` statement, not those ones which are more declarative in nature).

Comment: So would I have to use the split function?

Comment: I would think so but, from memory, Pythons string split uses a fixed separator (which will be okay if, for example, all your words are separated by a single space). If you want your code to be more versatile, the `re` module has its own split which can use a regular expression. The other complication you'll have is that you'll need to either 'process words' or 'process lines and remember what wordnumber you're up to' (i.e., carry that forward to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_but_n(file,num):
  rf=[]    #rf is the list containing words for the returned file
  n=num
  f=open(file,'r')
  i=0#for indexing the file
  for line in f:
    line=line.strip('\n').split(' ')
    for word in line:
      if n!=i+1:
        rf.append(word)
      else:
        n=n+num
      i=i+1
  return rf

all_but_n('',3)
```

You could most certainly use list comprehensions to improve the speed. I wrote all_but_n() in this manner, so that you could understand what's happening

Comment: It's common practice not to provide working answers to questions marked as homework.

Comment: I'm kind still fresh on python coding, what does the strip function do?

Comment: @wheaties, my bad, I didn't realize the presence of the homework tag.